# Последовательное считывание из потока вывода и потока ошибок при работе с CMD (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

Разрабатываю модуль для приложения, позволяющий работать с командными строками. Тестируюсь на CMD. Задача - позволить пользователю ввести пул команд для выполнения и получать результат по каждой из них, причем что всё выполнение должно находиться в одном сеансе консоли и результат по каждой из команд должен быть получен сразу после выполнения команды для возможности его использования в последующих командах.

Проблема в следующем - я где-то нашла классный метод получения ответа на команду, который здорово справляется с потоком output. Им же я пытаюсь получать поток error, но почему-то оно не работает так, как хотелось бы...

Если ошибочная команда идет первая - то все читается отлично. Если ошибочная команда идет после другой ошибочной команды, **и если не читать буфер первой команды**, то у второй ошибка считается. Если же считать у обеих - ничего не считается. Задача чтения (readAsync) висит якобы невыполненной. Если ошибочная команда одна и она где-то в середине других - ошибка снова **не** считается.

Вот основной метод обработки команд:

```
var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                FileName = "cmd",
                StandardOutputEncoding = enc,
                StandardErrorEncoding = enc
            });

            List<string> commands = new List<string>() { "ipconfig", "node -b","cd 123" };

            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            List<string> resultsErr = new List<string>();

            using (StreamWriter sr = process.StandardInput)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < commands.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (sr.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        sr.WriteLine((string)null); // для того, чтобы каждая команда начиналась с новой строки и можно было обрезать результат и выдавать его без лишних строк
                        sr.WriteLine(commands[i]);
                    }

                    var result = read(process, 1);
                    result = takeOnlyAnswer(result, commands[i]);
                    results.Add(result);

                    //тут где-то нужно придумать флаги? (читать или не читать)
                    var resultErr = read(process, 1, true);
                    resultErr = resultErr.TrimEnd('\r');
                    resultsErr.Add(resultErr);
                }
            }

            label1.Text = String.Join("\n", results);
            label2.Text = String.Join("\n", resultsErr);
```

и собственно метод чтения, честно стыренный с просторов интернета и чуть-чуть доработанный под свои нужны

```
private string read(Process process, int secondsWait = 1, bool err = false)
       {
           char[] buffer = new char[256];
           string output = "";
           Task<int> read = null;
           int countWait = secondsWait * 10;
           int count = 0;
           int countErr = 0;
           while (true)
           {
               while (read == null && countErr != countWait)
                   try
                   {
                       if (!err)
                           read = process.StandardOutput.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                       else
                           read = process.StandardError.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                   }
                   catch
                   {
                       countErr++;
                       Thread.Sleep(100);
                   }
               countErr = 0;
               if (read == null)
                   break;
               read.Wait(100); // an arbitray timeout

               if (read.IsCompleted)
               {
                   if (read.Result > 0)
                   {
                       output += new string(buffer, 0, read.Result);
                       read = null; 
                       count = 0;
                       continue;
                   }

                   break;
               }
               else if (read.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation && count == countWait)
               {
                   break;
               }
               count++;
           }
           return output;
       }
```

Метод takeOnlyAnswer просто обрезает лишние строки, оставляя чисто ответ от сообщения. Не очень важен.

Ошибка, наверное, с самим пониманием побайтового чтения...
Всю голову сломала, надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Возможно, ваша проблема описана здесь: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110707-00/?p=10223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в следующем.

Ваш код

```
var result = read(process, 1);
// ...
var resultErr = read(process, 1, true);
```

сначала читает из stdout, а затем из stderr. Если программа, которую вы запускаете, сначала пишет в stderr, что происходит?

1. Вы пытаетесть читать из stdout, пока в stdout ничего нету, ваш код ждёт.
2. Программа пишет в stderr. Поскольку запись происходит в pipe, то она (запись) идёт до исчерпания буфера, а потом останавливается, ожидая, что читающий процесс прочитает записанные байты.
3. Ваш код не читает ничего из stderr, т. к. вы ждёте, пока что-то появится в stdout. Но stdout будет закрыт лишь в конце работы программы, то есть после того, как отработает заблокированная запись в stderr.

Вот вам и deadlock.

---

Более простой код, который читает у процесса как stdout, так и stderr, можно найти [прямо в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror?view=net-5.0#remarks):

```
string stderr = null;
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) => 
                             { stderr += e.Data; });
process.Start();  
// To avoid deadlocks, use an asynchronous read operation on at least one of the streams.  
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
string stdout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();  
process.WaitForExit();
```

В конце работы в переменных `stdout` и `stderr` будет то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение! К сожалению, оно не подходит - мне нужен ответ и ошибка на каждую из задач, а не всё вместе. То есть пользователь ввел пул задач и хочет видеть ответ по каждой из них, а не по всем вместе.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Этот код вроде бы обрабатывает ровно одну задачу

Comment: А мне нужно обрабатывать несколько задач в одном сеансе и отдавать ответы по каждой задаче

Comment: Ну да, но я все равно покамест не вижу, в чем проблема

Comment: Спасибо, что убедили меня использовать ваш метод. Я глупая и упертая :)
Но такое чтение ошибки мне помогло, я просто передаю в него текущую обрабатываемую команду и по мере появления ошибки записываю ответ. Output же обрабатываю так же, как и раньше и всё отлично работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @narkaram: Главное, что один из потоков (например, stderr) читается асинхронно. Если так, как вы написали, работает, то и слава богу. Будут ещё проблемы — задавайте ещё вопросы. Удачи!